# How to place icon next to input field in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using using bootstrap in my project. I am creating an edit form in which i have to use some info icons next to input field and in this task i am facing an alignment problem. Please check this image:[image]

Notice the huge gap b/w input field and icon and the same problem is with selectlist and duration field. The html code of this image is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Services[0].FixedTimeSlot, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label small" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Services[0].FixedTimeSlot, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", data_bind = "value: FixedTimeSlot" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Services[0].FixedTimeSlot, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa fa-info-circle text-info icon-ms" data-bind=""></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Services[0].Duration, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label small" })
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Services[0].Duration, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", data_bind = "value: Duration" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="options: $parents[1].timeUnits, optionsText: 'unit', optionsValue: 'value', value: selectedTimeUnit"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Services[0].Duration, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am new with bootstrap and very week in css, so i do not want to write css, is this problem can be solved using bootsrap classes ??

Comment: This problem can be solved by placing the <span> containing the icon within the same col that your input is in. Placing the span containing the icon inside it's own column will cause it to align left inside of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Services[0].FixedTimeSlot, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label small" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Services[0].FixedTimeSlot, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", data_bind = "value: FixedTimeSlot" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Services[0].FixedTimeSlot, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
       <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa fa-info-circle text-info icon-ms" data-bind=""></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The classes col-md-X define a "box" for the div.
If you place the anchor inside the same div as the textbox, the icon should align.

Further reading: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/